# How to call API and render a new component

Tags: reactjs

What would be a way to call an API in a component class (do not use a functional component) and render the received data in a new component. I am asking for the order of operation to `setState`. My current solution includes `setState` and a function as a second argument that set anther state. Function `getStockInfo` calls API and then I want to render the `GetQuote` component switching `showComponent` to true. Note that in `ComponentDidMount` I call an initial API. Please let me know if this is a valid solution or there is a neater way.

```
class Portfolio extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      res: " ",
      data: [],
      showComponent: false,
    };

    this.showStockiaDetails = this.showStockDetails.bind(this);
    this.getStockInfo = this.getStockInfo.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  async getStockInfo(item) {
    const stock = item.symbol;
    const API_KEY = "1D";
    const PATH = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=${stock}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
    await axios
      .get(PATH)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ res: response.data }, () => this.showStockDetails());
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleClick(item) {
    this.getStockInfo(item);
  }

  showStockDetails() {
    console.log("-->", this.state.res);
    this.setState({ showComponent: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ data: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Day Eight</h1>
        <div className="row col-12">
          <div className="col-md-5 col-lg-4 ">
            <ul className="list-group">
              {this.state.dayeightData.map((s) => (
                <li
                  key={s.id}
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(s)}
                  className="list-group-item"
                  aria-current="true"
                >
                  {s.symbol}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 col-lg-8 order-md-last">
            {this.state.showComponent ? (
              <GetQuote stock={this.state.res} />
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Portfolio;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did it right. There would be many other alternatives too depending on what GetQuote component is rendering. To make it look a little bit more cleaner you can do something like this:

```
{
this.state.res ? <GetQuote stock={this.state.res} /> : ''
}
```

But make sure to initialize `res` as "" (without any space) as ""  will be false and " " will be true.
In that way, you don't really have to call `showStockDetails` function.

Comment: Thank you Mayank. Do you know me where to read about other alternatives?

Comment: The alternatives could be very specific depending on what type of components you want to mount after API call in the DOM tree. You can search for some good react projects on GitHub which has loading components. I am sure you will find one for your use-case.